# Setting up bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I feel quite silly asking this question, but I just cant seem to figure it out.

I wanted to try out the Twitter bootstap theme, so i downloaded the files and tried setting up a very basic example page. Here is the code for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>With Bootstrap</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>

 <body>
    <p>Hello Bootstrap!</p>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm pretty sure i've got the files in the correct location (I checked the source from chrome, and followed the link to the stylesheet to verify this). However it seems like the CSS is not quite working on the document since I just get a default styled page and not the bootstrap version. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that your stylesheets and script files are loading correctly?

Comment: Where are `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` stored in reference to the page ? Are they in the same folder ?

Comment: I think boostrap also requires less right?
http://www.lesscss.org/

Comment: No, it's written using less but doesn't require it.

Comment: What do you expect ? You only got a `<p>` in here.

Comment: yes they the stylesheet and the js file are in the same folder as the html document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to get started is to use the Bootstrap files from BootstrapCDN..

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
            <title></title>
            <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>    
    <div class="container">

    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p>Use this document as a way to quick start any new project.<br> All you get is this message and a barebones HTML document.</p>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If this works, then you know to double check the paths for your local Bootstrap files.

Comment: Tried that. Still no luck. I also tried a couple of different browsers. Didn't work either

Comment: Did you try using Bootstrap markup in the body (ie: `<div class="container">`)?

Comment: Aaah..It was just using a header and a p and expecting it to look like the templates. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it's working for you. You may find the templates at http://Bootply.com helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to put all your content is a div with a 'container' class on it.
Make also sure that the 'bootstrap.min.css' is at the same level as your current HTML file.
If not, change the 'href' value.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your code example my first thought is that you are not utilizing any of the bootstrap classes to style your markup.

Try this:

```
<p class="text-error">Hello Bootstrap!</p>
```

This should render the text in red.  There some great examples in the bootstrap documentation found at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html.  You must indicate in your markup which Bootstrap directives to use.

Here's a more complete example that will give a two-column layout with an anchor tag turned into a button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>With Bootstrap</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span8">
                    <!--Sidebar content-->
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">This link looks like a button!</a>
                </div>
                <div class="span4">
                    <!--Body content-->
                    <p class="text-success">Isn't this great?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this helps you get started!